# JavaScript Intl API gives different results in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, datetime, timezone

I am using JavaScript Intl API to detect the user's timezone in the browser:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

While this API [looks stable](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/#test-DateTimeFormat_resolvedOptions().timeZone_defaults_to_the_host_environment), I don't know what to do with the next. On my Windows 10 machine, the timezone is set to `US Eastern Standard Time`:

```
C:\> tzutil /g
US Eastern Standard Time
```

In Firefox and Edge the above JavaScript code results with `"America/Indiana/Indianapolis"`, while Chrome returns just `"America/Indianapolis"`.

Why this yields different results in different browsers? Is it a Chrome bug or should I transform the time zones somehow before processing them on the server?

On Ubuntu (which is my server's OS), if I list available time zones with `timedatectl list-timezones`, there is `"America/Indiana/Indianapolis"`, but **there is no** `"America/Indianapolis"`. Because of this issue I cannot accept Chrome's `"America/Indianapolis"` from the client, as I grab the "available time zones list" from the output of `timedatectl list-timezones`. Which behavior should I apply here?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, both are the same - check their names in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (one is a link to another). Check also [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/backward)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35781/why-is-zone-tab-missing-so-many-time-zones

Comment: @Hugo, thank you. Does the "backward" file you linked provide the complete list of "time zone aliases"? What should be the algorithm? Looks like if I have LINK-NAME with the exact timezone name, I need to change it to TARGET in that table. Is this correct? Could you answer a question then?

Comment: This file is maintained by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (which is used by lots of applications and languages) and it's probably the most complete we can have. Regarding *"what should be the algorithm?"*, it depends on how your applications deal with timezones. In Java, for example, both names work and are equivalent. Not sure how browsers and JavaScript wil handle both names, but probably using `America/Indiana/Indianapolis` is better as it's the most recent name. Not sure why Chrome still uses the old one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome, like many others, gets its time zone information through [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), which in turn sources from [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/), which in part sources from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

There is a subtle difference between IANA and CLDR with regard to *canonicalization*.

- IANA treats the *preferred* form of the time zone identifier as canonical.  If the preferred form changes, they make the new one primary (a `Zone` entry) and move the old one to an alias (a `Link` entry).
- CLDR treates the *first* form of the time zone identifier as canonical.  That is, the first time it appeared in CLDR, it is locked in forever.  If a new form ever appears, it is added as an alias in the [`/common/bcp47/timezone.xml`](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/bcp47/timezone.xml) file.

Taking your case of Indianapolis:

- IANA Zone entry ([reference here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/northamerica#L796))

  ```
  Zone    America/Indiana/Indianapolis    ...
  ```
- IANA Link entry ([reference here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/backward#L18))

  ```
  Link    America/Indiana/Indianapolis    America/Indianapolis
  ```
- In CLDR, the primary zone is listed first in the "aliases" attribute, followed by other aliases.  ([reference here](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/bcp47/timezone.xml))

  ```xml
  <type name="usind" description="Indianapolis, United States" alias="America/Indianapolis America/Fort_Wayne America/Indiana/Indianapolis US/East-Indiana"/>
  ```

The same thing can be found with `Asia/Calcutta` vs. `Asia/Kolkata` and several other examples.

Additionally, be aware that the Windows time zone mappings also source from CLDR, in the [`/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml`](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) file.  You'll notice there that `US Eastern Standard Time` is mapped to `America/Indianapolis`.  **So the difference between browsers depends very much on which canonicalization rules are followed.**

In the end, it doesn't really matter which alias is used.  They point at the same data.

Also worth pointing out, that particular Windows zone should only be selected if you care about [historical time changes in Indiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana).  If you are just in the US Eastern time zone, you should set your system to `"Eastern Standard Time"`, rather than `"US Eastern Standard Time"`. (Yes, those IDs are confusing...)

Comment: Thank you very much on such expanded description! Everything definitely makes sense. In fact, I came to this question in my project from Moment.js with moment-timezone (as well as from a bunch of other libraries), because using these libraries literally doubles the processing time, which is critical (my project builds multi-dimensional pivot tables based on calendar data). So instead of dealing with time zones and replacing the awesome `Date` object (NodeJS), I decided to launch workers using clustering, and initialize each worker to a particular timezone, which is possible in NodeJS/V8.

Comment: Great answer! I always thought that browsers read these info directly from the SO. And I'm not surprised that each one follows different rules - the more I learn about this, the more confusing it seems.

Comment: @Hugo - Welcome to my world. ;)

Comment: To be clear, much of the utc-to-local (such as the `Date` object) does indeed happen based on the operating system's native APIs.  It's all the other stuff (like ECMA-402/Intl) that is usually routed through something like ICU.

Comment: It seems weird that the *resolvedOptions* object doesn't a property with the actual offset. I also don't understand why *locale* uses a language code (why not call it "language") and *timeZone* uses a locality (why not use that for *locale*). Why not include an offset property that has the actual offset? I guess that's why I'm not a standards writer. :-(

Answer (score 1):

zone.tab is incomplete. Some time zones are represented as symbolic links:

```
$ find /usr/share/zoneinfo/America -name Indianapolis -exec file {} \;
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Indiana/Indianapolis: symbolic link to ../Indianapolis
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Indianapolis: timezone data, version 2, 7 gmt time flags, 7 std time flags, no leap seconds, 99 transition times, 7 abbreviation chars
```

Comment: Thank you Josh! What would be the best way to get the list of all available time zones then? To `find` through `/usr/share/zoneinfo`? The purpose of having this list is to be able to validate the timezone which user requested before processing any data (in my case, spawning a new process, doing computations, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how/why each browser returns a different result (probably they read from different sources and/or it can be due to how each implements `Intl.DateTimeFormat`). But it doesn't matter, because both are the same timezone.

If you check [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), you'll see that `America/Indianapolis` links to `America/Indiana/Indianapolis`. Those names in the format `Region/City` are maintained by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) and it's probably one of the best sources we have about timezone information.

IANA also keeps a [backward file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/backward) that maps those 2 names, with `America/Indiana/Indianapolis` being the most recent one.

So one alternative is to get a copy of the backward file and use it to map whatever name you receive to the respective new name, and also validate against your server's timezone list.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I will end up by adding aliases from [the backward file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/backward) to the results of `timedatectl list-timezones`, this way creating a (complete?) list of available time zones.

Comment: @ZitRo You're welcome! The list will be as complete as it can be. Timezones are defined by governments and laws, and politicians [love to change them](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time) for whatever reasons they have (see the [list of changes in git](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commits/master) to have an idea). Of course a **new** timezone is less common than changing the rules of existing zones, but you must keep this file always updated if you want to have a "complete" list. Good luck!