# Moment Timezone returns correct timezone but with wrong spelling

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using MomentJS Timezone. However, when I do `moment.tz.guess()`, it returns my timezone with wrong spelling.

```
const timezone = moment.tz.guess();
console.log(timezone); //returns Asia/Katmandu instead of Asia/Kathmandu
```

Yes, I could've just edited the js file and corrected the spelling but I'm afraid it's same for other countries too. Since I will be unaware of it, this might degrade the user experience!

Is this behavior expected or is there any way to fix it?

**SEE THIS:**
[Correct Timezone List [Moment] [Javascript] [PHP] [Internationalization API]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435459/correct-timezone-list-moment-javascript-php-internationalization-api)

Comment: Try to use a custom locale

Comment: Try reporting an issue on the moment.js github. I don't know what any of us here can do about this.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/159)

Comment: Which version of moment-timezone are you using?

Comment: @VincenzoC I am using `"moment": "^2.22.2",` and `"moment-timezone": "^0.5.21"`! P.S. I still couldn't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using moment 2.2.22 and 0.5.17 data, here is the result I found.

```js
var timezones = moment.tz.names();
console.log(moment.tz.guess());
for (var i = 0; i < timezones.length; i++) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(timezones[i]);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("mm").appendChild(node);

}
```

```css
#mm span {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<ul id='mm'></ul>
```

My result showed that there are two names coming for same timezone (Kathmandu and Katmandu), which has written like `Asia/Kathmandu|Asia/Katmandu` (one updated second obsolete). After researching slight a bit I found this is because obsolete timezone and chrome behaviour this issue will not occur on Firefox or any other browser.

This issue is also not going to be resolved by developers as this doesn't create any problem. This is a known Chrome behaviour that leads to Moment making an incorrect guess. The Moment development team is uninterested in developing a workaround. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3852).

So I would suggest you use string and format it according to your need and suggested on the previous answer.

### Note

Please test the example in other browsers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I did is I made a list of correct timezones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435459/correct-timezone-list-moment-javascript-php-internationalization-api

Comment: Instead of stack can't you start a git project, I will surely contribute in that. And is that mean that the bounty is not going to be awarded.

Comment: Sure! I will start a git project. Will talk to you after finishing it!

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45867761/3551786) why results differ. 
If you are getting result `Asia/Katmandu` return value as `Asia/Kathmandu`.

```js
//for kathmandu, it returns Asia/Katmandu(chrome)
//returns Asia/Kathmandu (firfox);
var timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
if(timeZone === 'Asia/Katmandu'){
  timeZone = 'Asia/Kathmandu';
}
console.log(timeZone);
```

***MomentJs DEMO***

```js
var timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
if(timeZone === 'Asia/Katmandu'){
  timeZone = 'Asia/Kathmandu';
}
console.log(timeZone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then what should I exactly do to fix this? I went through the post you suggested. I understood what's going on but still couldn't figure out how to fix the issue.

Comment: @Sanjay, only option I get is, check the string and replace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what if it is same with other continents too? I am worried about it because I store this timezone in MySQL Database and use this data to do `date_default_timezone_set()` in PHP!

Comment: @Sanjay then it will defer the result for `Asia/Calcutta` which valid is `Asia/Kolkata`. Here is supported [time zone list](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/timezones.html). You need to store the time zone accordingly.