# How to ignore IANA backward compatible values of timezone in moment js library or javascript Intl API?

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone, angular-moment

I am using moment-timezone package to get current time zone values.
I need value like America/New_york, Asia/KolKatta.

```
import * as Moment from 'moment-timezone';
Moment.tz.guess()
```

It works fine, but gives Asia/Calcutta instead of Asia/KolKatta.
Another solution for getting timezone name I found is

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

Related Question on SO [Moment Timezone returns correct timezone but with wrong spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232297/moment-timezone-returns-correct-timezone-but-with-wrong-spelling)

Please suggest if someone knows the solution to fix this issue in Javascript?

Comment: Asia/Calcutta exists in IANA timezone database for backward compability (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). What `moment-timezone` does with `guess` method is that it first tries to use `Intl` API. If successful (compatible), then it returns the result. Else, the library tries to find the zone with its own algorithm (results are alphabetically sorted -> Asia/Calcutta > Asia/Kolkata). I am not sure about `Intl` API `resolvedOptions` method but it may also get alphabetically first result.

Comment: Hi @alpakyol Thanks for the insights. I had no idea about this priority. Is there any way to fetch second option? because my backend is in PHP and it used the second value.

Comment: In either ways, the library will return same results in my opinion. From docs: _It then compares that information with all the time zone data loaded and returns the closest match. In case of ties, the time zone with the city with largest population is returned_.