# Intl.supportedValuesOf('timezone') doesn't provide the latest timezone information

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, intl, ecmascript-intl

I want to obtain the most up-to-date timezone list. I'm using `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')`, and here's the output, for instance:

- 'Asia/Saigon'
- 'Pacific/Ponape'

The cities mentioned above have been deprecated. For example, when I researched the `'Asia/Saigon'` timezone, I found that it has been renamed to `'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'`, and `'Pacific/Ponape'` no longer exists as a valid timezone.

I'm curious about why `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` doesn't provide the latest timezone information.

Is there an alternative method to obtain the most current timezone list? Thank you.

Comment: Why? Either because your browser hasn't been updated, or - more likely - because they still support legacy timezone names to not break things. No, there is no other builtin method. If you care about versioning the list of valid timezone names, better maintain it yourself.

Comment: The maintainer of IANA timezones and representative locations is [IANA](https://www.iana.org), details are [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6557.html). If you want the most recent list, download it from [here](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a known bug.  Some links to issues: [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43678), [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-enumeration/issues/47), and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=13084).  Probably others.

The cause is that the list comes from an ICU function call, which is returning only the "canonical" zones (according to ICU/CLDR, not IANA), excluding aliases, and also excluding the system (`Etc/*`) zones.

In other words, this is an implementation bug in V8 and other JS engines, not a bug with JavaScript itself.

Comment: More on why there are differences between IANA and CLDR with regard to canonicalization as part of one of my other answers on this subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868768/634824

Comment: None of the bug reports you linked are about the exclusion of deprecated timezone values. If anything, they are about the *inclusion* of more values.

Comment: @Bergi - the first one doesn't?

Comment: Also - these aren't just about deprecated values.  It's that perfectly valid aliases, which are sometimes the current IANA `Zone` entry, are not in the list.  For example, `Asia/Kolkata` is the current and preferred identifier for India, according to IANA - but is absent from the list because it's an alias in the CLDR data.

Comment: The issue might be related, but it's says "*it would be good if `Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` would output all valid values even the ones coming from the system.*" That's not what the OP of the SO question here is asking: they want deprecated timezones to be *removed* from the output, so the exact opposite.

Comment: But yes, the [difference between IANA and CLDR data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45868768/634824) you linked does explain the cause of the issue: the "deprecated" timezone is still the canonical CLDR name

Comment: Looks like there is work underway to resolve these canonicalization differences.   Hopefully that will address this issue as well.  See https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/806, https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/pull/3105, and https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-14453

Comment: Yes, I think https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/806 perfectly applies to the OPs problem!